# blueImp upload from existing form

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to get blueimp to upload from a form. In the below example when I call FileUpload from the file input tag it works as expected. When I assign it to the form tag it fails.

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="file_upload" type="file" name="files[]" />
  <input type="text" name="test"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/test/'
  }); 
});
</script>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: So you're saying if the `<input>` file upload field is within a `<form>` it fails but if the file upload `<input>` field is outside the form it works correctly?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the input tag is inside or outside the form tag

Comment: Do you get an error message or anything when it fails?

Comment: What do you have in */test* folder?

Comment: I'm currently working on trying to do the same thing ... if I figure it out I'll share what I find.